# How can I combine two if-statements into one?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

What is the simplest way to combine the following two if-statements into one if-statement?

```
if(n===1) return 0;
if(n===2) return 1;​
```

Comment: I guest the answer is another question : why would you want to do that ? You've got code that's decently short and easy to read. Why mess it up ?

Comment: I was challenged to reduce it to using only one if-statement.

Answer (score 7):

**1)** If you want to return for all numbers

You could simply say

```
return n-1;
```

**2):** If you want just for these two values

```
if (n === 1 || n === 2) return n-1;
```

Or something like bellow

```
[1,2].indexOf(n) //but this could be a tricky way.
```

Comment: This is, of course, *different* from the OP's code in that it always returns. We don't know what follows the quoted code in the OP's stuff.

Comment: This doesn't behave the same if `n` is `42`

Answer (score 5):

```
if (n === 1 || n === 2) return n-1;
```